# Error al ingresar con una cuenta luego de cambiar la contraseña encriptada Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, hash

tengo un problema al ingresar en mi app con una cuenta luego de haber cambiado la contraseña y encriptandola, ella se guarda en la bd (Mysql) correctamente y hasta tengo un campo donde me muestra la nueva contraseña y valido que si todo esta perfecto, pero al salirme de esa cuenta y volver a entrar me dice que la contraseña es incorrecta aun que todo este bien, busque varias soluciones pero no creo que sea problema del encriptado ya que al registrar usuario hace lo mismo con la contraseña y no me da esos errores, solo es al cambiarla.

Aqui esta mi codigo:

Mi Input:

```
<div class="card-content"> Desea cambiar su contraseña?<br><br> 
                                                 <div class="input-field col s12">
                                                   <i class="material-icons prefix blue-text">edit</i>
                                                   <label>Contraseña Antigua</label>
                                                   {!! Form::open(['url'=>['ChangePassword',$user],'method'=>'POST', 'files'=>true,'class'=>'form-horizontal','id'=>'edit']) !!}
                                                     {!! Form::text('password',$user->password,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}   
                                                    </div>

                                                 <a href="{{ url('ChangePassword', $user->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary green curvaBoton active modal-close">Actualizar</a>
                                                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary green curvaBoton active modal-close">Volver</a>
                                                  {!! Form::close() !!} 
                                              </div>
```

Mi Controlador:(OJO, lo que esta comentado son otras maneras que probe de encriptar la contraseña y aun que todas funcionan me da el mismo error al ingresar de nuevo con la cuenta)

```
 public function changepassword(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    //$user->password = $request->password;
    //$newpassword = bcrypt($request->newpassword);
    //$confirmnewpass = bcrypt($request->confirmnewpass);
    //$encrypted = Crypt::encryptString($user->password);
    //$user->password = $encrypted;
    //$decrypted = Crypt::decrypt($request->password);
    //$user->password = $decrypted;
    //$user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    //$user->password = $user->password;
    //$user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
    //$pass_encrypt = md5($request->password); 
    $pass_encrypt = password_hash($user->password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $user->password = $pass_encrypt;  

    if (password_verify($user->password, $pass_encrypt));
    //if (Hash::check($request->password, $pass_encrypt))
   //{
    {
        $user->save();

          return redirect()->action('UserController@edit');

         Flash('Se ha modificado sus contraseña con exito!')->success();
    } 

  // } 

}
```

Y finalmente mi ruta:

```
Route::get('ChangePassword/{id}','UserController@changepassword');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema en tu código se origina en esta línea:

```
$pass_encrypt = password_hash($user->password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

El password que estás encriptando es el actual y no el que te pasan a través del *request*.

En la práctica, lo que haces es utilizar el password actual encriptado como nuevo password. Es decir, estableces el hash que está almacenado en la BBDD como nuevo password.

Con esto en cuenta, esta línea debería quedar así:

```
$pass_encrypt = password_hash($request->get('password'), PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

Comment: ¿Establece el hash o un hash del propio hash?

Comment: Utiliza el hash del password actual como nuevo password. Al momento de guardarlo hashea este nuevo password por seguridad quedando, en la práctica, un hash de un hash.

Comment: Gracias por tu pronta respuesta, tienes razón en tu observación pero ya hice el cambio y aun así me sigue dando el mismo error al ingresar con la cuenta.

Comment: Agregue un dd o var_dump y me fije que al enviar por el post la variable password me la esta devolviendo como "null" en vez de lo que le este colocando en el input, sera que tengo un error en la sintaxis del form? si alguien puede ayudarme a revisar ya que soy nuevo trabajando en laravel y esa sintaxis solo al estoy sobrescribiendo del proyecto ya existente.

Comment: En este caso me parece que es culpa mía que me confundí con Symfony. En vez de *$request->get('password')*, utiliza *$request->input('password')*

Comment: Si aún así te llega **null**, depura los datos que llegan dumpeando *$request->all();* y fijate si se está pasando correctamente el nuevo password.

Comment: es correcto, no se están pasando los datos no me trae nada desde el input, creo que ese es el problema, me estaba era tomando la clave antigua y encriptandola como tu habias mencionado, ahora tengo que ver es por que no me trae los datos desde el input del password. aun estoy aprendiendo con laravel.

Comment: Realmente no he usado laravel en el último tiempo pero lo que me genera dudas de tu form es:
    <a href="{{ url('ChangePassword', $user->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary green curvaBoton active modal-close">Actualizar</a>
No estoy seguro de que ese enlace reemplace a primeras buenas la funcionalidad del botón Submit.

Comment: Listo Esta resuelvo! El problema principal si era que estaba tomando la contraseña vieja y enciptandola, luego lo del formulario también tenias razón Roberto tuve que cambiar todo el form con el formato de blade de laravel mediante post y ya esta! Muchas gracias!l